# Anyone who has the ESRI Census 2000 Tiger/Line data?

Tags: data, census, tiger

The ESRI Census 2000 TIGER/Line Data were free.

http://www.esri.com/data/download/census2000-tigerline
http://arcdata.esri.com/data/tiger2000/tiger_download.cfm

But they vanished. The download link is broken. Is there anyone out there who has the data?

Answer (score 4):

The source data is available at http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html. Note that the 2000 series tab provides data in the old ASCII format, but you can get the Census tracts by US state for 2000 in shapefile format from [a page off the 2010 tab](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/layers.cgi).

Other than that, I can only suggest contacting ESRI.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a python code to cover the report type (.RT) files to the shapefiles.
Welcome to check out my code from my GitHub site:
https://github.com/zxy1219/2000-Census-TIGER-LINE

I also put an brief tutorial about how to use python in ArcMAP. You are always welcome to contact me if you have any questions.

Sue-ying